A question about $p$-adic value of the sum $a^n+b^n+c^n$
Given a prime $p$ and integers $x,y,z,a,b,c$ such that $(a,p)=(b,p)=(c,p)=1$.
Then whether this statement is true or false:

The inequation $v_p(x\cdot a^n+y\cdot b^n+z\cdot c^n)\geq n$ has finitely integer solutions ?

I think this statement is true but don't know how to prove it.
